# User removed: and points deducted

Tags: discussion

I just lost 16 points because a "user was removed".

[image: lost rep]

and

[image: list]

When does `-2` happen? I (honestly) can't remember participating in those questions in any way at all. And so I can't see, at least from the image, why the points were deducted.

Comment: [Related MSO Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those were questions you edited in your pre 2k days, and they have since been deleted (either the question, answer or user). I'm not sure why the rep gets removed, I myself think a good edit is a good edit period..

Comment: Thank you for pointing the out edit stuff. I had forgotten all about the +2's I got that way.

Comment: If a user was removed, aren't their posts (and thus the revisions) retained?

Comment: @minerz029 I guess I should have been more clear on that. There are two types of user deletions, delete and destroy. If a user is destroyed all his posts go with him. Granted, it doesn't happen too often.

Comment: @Seth and everyone else, [this MSO post may be relevant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)